# Is it possible to convert 4:3 pictures to 16:9 using Python (2.7)

Tags: python, image-processing, image-editing

I have been searching the net for a while, but to no avail!  Is there an image editing library for python that will allow me to convert 4:3 pictures to 16:9?

Any information and/or links are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to crop, resize, ...?

Comment: Are you planning on cropping the image, or stretching the image?

Comment: The answer to most "Is it possible" question is "Yes."  Please fix the question so the answer isn't a trivial "Yes."  Perhaps you should ask something more focused on what you're trying to do and what code you've written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For naive resizing using one of a few various filter types, you can use [`Image.resize`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.resize) from the PIL:

> `im.resize(size)` => image
>
> `im.resize(size, filter)` => image
>
> Returns a resized copy of an image. The size argument gives the requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: `(width, height)`.
>
> The filter argument can be one of NEAREST (use nearest neighbour), BILINEAR (linear interpolation in a 2x2 environment), BICUBIC (cubic spline interpolation in a 4x4 environment), or ANTIALIAS (a high-quality downsampling filter). If omitted, or if the image has mode "1" or "P", it is set to NEAREST.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) has the ability to do this.